# AngularJS: applying dynamic class on button that called it

Tags: html, css, angularjs

sorry the title may be confusing, but what I am trying to do is dynamically change a class based on a button click. However, this works on every tag except the ons-button that calls the changToRed function.

```
<div ng-controller="clickCtrl">
    <ons-button ng-class="dynamic" ng-click="changeToRed()">Red</ons-button>
</div>
```

Here is my main.js file:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp');

myApp.controller('clickCtrl', function($scope){

$scope.dynamic = "blue";

$scope.changeToRed = function(){
  $scope.dynamic = "red";      
}

$scope.changeToGreen = function(){
  $scope.dynamic = "green";
}

$scope.changeToBlue = function(){
  $scope.dynamic = "blue";      
}

});
```

Thanks,
Ben

Comment: Could you add your changeToRed function to the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ons-button is using ng-class internally. If you don't need the spinner animation, you can just use the class version.

```
<button ng-class="dynamic" ng-click="changeToRed()" class="topcoat-button">Red</button>
```

You also need to add !important to your css.

```
.red {
    background-color: red !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that fixed everything! Also, what is the reason for !important here? It seems to work with and without it.

Comment: Really? in my case, the it got overridden, so I use !important.

Comment: Yes, that is strange. One more thing, when I leave the page the dynamic class reverts to blue and not the last clicked one. The buttons that I am affecting are on a different page than the ones with the changeToX funcion.

Comment: is there a fix for the issue above?

Comment: what do you mean by leaving the page? are you using tab-bar and switching to another tab?

Comment: I am using presentPage() and dismissPage() on the page with the ChangTo__ buttons. I also added the dynamic class to buttons on a separate page, but once I dismiss the page with the ChangeTo__ buttons then the dynamic class reverts back to the default.

Comment: I think need to store the data locally. Would this be the case?

Comment: I think you have this flow:
1. present the 'clickCtrl' page
2. change dynamic to another color
3. dimiss the 'clickCtrl' page
4. present the 'clickCtrl' page
5. the value reverted back.

if this is the flow you have having, you need to store the dynamic value in the service because when a page is dismissed, any controllers inside them will be destroyed. so when you present them again, it will reconstruct any controllers inside that page.

Comment: Yes that is my flow. How would I store the dynamic value in the service?

Comment: You can follow this tutorial to which store the list data in a service. http://blog.asial.co.jp/1219?lang=en

Answer (score 1):

It is an issue with [AngularJS' scope](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes). It is a long article, but the part you need is about scope dot notation. Change your controller to this:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp');

myApp.controller('clickCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.model = {};
  $scope.model.dynamic = "blue";

  $scope.changeToRed = function(){
    $scope.model.dynamic = "red";
  }

  $scope.changeToGreen = function(){
    $scope.model.dynamic = "green";
  }

  $scope.changeToBlue = function(){
    $scope.model.dynamic = "blue";
  }
});
```

And then change your HTML to this:

```
<div ng-controller="clickCtrl">
    <ons-button ng-class="model.dynamic" ng-click="changeToRed()">Red</ons-button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for responding; however I am still getting the same problem. If I put ng-class="model.dynamic" in a h1 tag in the div then everything works properly, but not when the class is assigned to the ons-button. Maybe this is because it already has a class assigned. The set class is .topcoat-button  thanks

Comment: Is there any way I can assign the dynamic colors to an ID? Is there an ID form of ng-class?